# How to get specific sequence of array given the array size and the beginning

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list, loops

I have the following case :

a list or array .the size is a variable i get from the user between 1 to 12 .

if the size is 3 then the array {1,2,3}

if the size is 5 then the array {1,2,3,4,5}

and so on

Now the beginning is a variable also.

the sequence i wanna to get is :

if the size 12 for example ,and the beginning is 9 for example

i wanna the following result with this specific order.

`9`,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

I mean i begin with the given beginning until the last item then if the beginning not `1` then i continue with `1` until the beginning.

I did that but it was specific to the size `12`:

with this code :

---

```
        int[] arr = new int[12];
        int month = 9;//input from the user
        List<int> source = new List<int>();
        while (month <= 12)
        {
            source.Add(month);
            month++;
        }
        if (source.Count < 12)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < source[0]; i++)
            {
                source.Add(i);
            }
        }
```

---

I wanna more general solution to allow variable size not just `12`

Comment: you are almost close. line 1 doesnt need a array variable. just take some int variable like, int lenght = 12. now replace 12 by variable length in your while loop and if condition.

Edit: you can give input to length from a function too, which returns 12 for number of months, 30 or 31 for number of days, etc etc

Comment: please find three solutions below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested it and it works

```
                int arrsize = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                int[] arr = new int[arrsize];
                int month = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());//input from the user
                List<int> source = new List<int>();
                while (month <= arrsize)
                {
                    source.Add(month);
                    month++;
                }
                if (source.Count < arrsize)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i < source[0]; i++)
                    {
                        source.Add(i);
                    }
                }
                foreach (int i in source)
                    Console.Write(i);
```

Please add some conditions like array size should not be less than month and user always input integer and do it in try catch for good practice... etc etc

After using some logic from other answers i think below code is much better.

```
                int arrsize = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                int month = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());//input from the user
                List<int> source = new List<int>();
                int temp = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < arrsize; i++)
                {
                    temp = i + month;
                    if (temp != arrsize)
                        source.Add(((i + month) % arrsize));
                    else
                        source.Add(arrsize);
                }
```

The second method has less complexity only O (n) because it uses only one loop rather 2.

Third Solution is even more simpler :)

```
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {
                    if (i < month)
                        source.Add(i + month);
                    else
                        source.Add((i - month) + 1);
                }
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
        static IEnumerable<int> GetSequence(int size, int beginning)
        {
          return Enumerable.Range(beginning, size).Select(i => 1 + (i - 1) % 12);
        }
```

You can change the number `12` into a third parameter of the method.

Comment: @just_name Yes, it's the value where we "wrap around" to 1 again.

Comment: This is hard coded solution in terms of 12. he wants a generic. some thing like % size. But i like your solution elegant and simple :)

Answer (score 1):

```
static int[] Sequence(int size, int start)
{
    start--;
    int[] result = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        result[i] = ((i + start) % size ) + 1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your correct code would be int temp = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {
                    temp = i + start;
                    if (temp != arrsize)
                        result[i] = (temp % size);
                    else
                        result [i] =  temp;
                }

Comment: The reason for that is 12%12 will be 0 so when size is same as i + start you dont need to do %.

Comment: My code yields afaik the correct result. Your optimization  substitutes a modulo operation with an assignment and an if-statement. I doubt that it accounts for more optimal or correct code.

Comment: Yes my code might not be optimized than yours...but i have run your code and it gives incorrect result if you follow question author examples. that's all. Your code is definitely optimized.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's a matter of 1- og 0-indexed arrays. Which isn't an excuse of course :), but I tested and found the results satisfactory, since I by default assumes 0-indexes Sequence(12,0) gives [1:12], but you're quite right it should probably be S(12,1) => [1:12]. So the simplest solution would probably be to decrease start in the Sequence method (which is the case in the edit.)

Comment: BTW: In these cases I whink simplicity should be the goal why I actually prefer Jeppe Stig Nielsens solution to my own.